# spark3.0 on kubernetes with privileged containers

Tags: apache-spark, docker-privileged

How to start a container with "privileged=true", before spark2.4, we can add a securityContext.withPrivileged(true) in SparkPod.scala to set it, but spark3.0 does not seem to respect this anymore.  Any ideas?  Thank you